# Derived class cannot be transformed into base class in assignment

Tags: c++

I have defined two classes like this:

```
class A{};
class B : public A{};
```

And I've also defined a function to return a pointer to B:

```
B* func();
```

Why can't I do something like this?

```
A* a = NULL;
a = func();
```

I thought I was using dynamic binding, but apprently I was wrong.

-----------------update----------------------------

Sorry I was wrong, I was working on a big project so that error message didn't work well.

The problem was caused by header files since A and B were defined respectively in different header files.

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71c2b586dfdee6da). Can you please provide an actual [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It works. Please provide the actual code and the error message.

Comment: Posting the compiler error you get will be helpful, but note that the cpp file that calls a = func() must include the header file that defines class B : public A{};. If you only have forward declarations (e.g. class A; class B;), the compiler will not know the relationship between the two classes.

Comment: @birdypme thank you, I found that something may be wrong with the header file after some debug work.

Comment: @laxus you're welcome. I suppose accepting Vlad's answer would be a good step, as he has made the effort to write the full sample code that compiles and works for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample program compiles successfully

```
#include <iostream>

class A { public: virtual ~A() = default; };
class B : public A {};

B* func() { return new B(); }

int main() 
{
    A *a = func();

    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```